# Main report not filled but subreports are

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm having a bit of an issue when generating jasper reports in java. The setup works perfectly in iReport IDE. The way I'm creating the report is as follows:

```
private void createReport(String dataSourceXml) throws JRException{

        String outFilename = dataSourceXml.replace(".xml", ".pdf");
        String main = res.getString("main_jrxml.dir");
        String sub1 = res.getString("sub1_jrxml.dir");
        String sub2 = res.getString("sub2_jrxml.dir");
        String sub3 = res.getString("sub3_jrxml.dir");


        JasperReport sub3Report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sub3);
        JasperReport sub2Report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sub2);
        JasperReport sub1Report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sub1);
        JasperReport mainReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(main);

        JRXmlDataSource xmlDatasource = new JRXmlDataSource(new File(dataSourceXml));

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put("sub1", sub1);
        params.put("sub2", sub2);
        params.put("sub3", sub3);


        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(mainReport, params, xmlDatasource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outFilename);
    }
```

The report get created and all the subreports gets filled but not the main report.

Can anybody advice what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to figure out why the fields from main report are not being filled. I worked around it by simply adding another subreport instead and this is working fine for me.

Pity that Jasper documentation is so horrible.